# Using lazy evaluation on a large regular expression (and not just .*?)

Tags: php, regex, reluctant-quantifiers

Using the follow regex:

```
\[\w* \w* \d{2} [\w:]* \d{4}\] \[error\] \[client .*?\] .*? Using HTTP not .*?<br />
```

I get the following results (where yellow boxes indicate a match):

[image: Sublime Text 2]

*Raw Text:* http://pastebin.com/vSi0mLGv

The bottom two sections are correct. I want all sections that contain: `&lt;&lt;&lt;NOTICE&gt;&gt;&gt; Non-Prod Server: Using HTTP not HTTP/S`

The top section however, contains the correct string (similar to the bottom two), but also comes with a whole other chunk that I do not want:

```
[Thu May 10 17:43:48 2012] [error] [client ::1] Current Name:
DashboardBar_projAnnualReview200, referer: http://
localhost/test/pages/TestPage.php<br />`
```

I know this comes down to regex being greedy, but how can I go about making it do a lazy evaluation for the `<br />`, if that's even the right way to go about it. I've tried `(<br />)*?` and others to no avail.

---

Other Information:
I am using [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2), and performing a regex search if anyone wanted to recreate the image.

Comment: Just FYI, [lazy evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) has nothing to do with regexes.  The word "lazy" was used early on to describe the non-greedy variant of regex quantifiers, and it was a mistake.  "Non-greedy" is a much better word for them, and "reluctant" even more accurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Greediness is not the problem, *eagerness* is.  The regex engine starts trying to match at the earliest opportunity, and it doesn't give up until every possibility has been exhausted.  Making quantifiers non-greedy doesn't change that, it just changes the order in which the possibilities are tried.

It's not the `*` in `.*` that's causing your problem, it's the `.`.  You need to use something more restrictive, because it's allowing the match to start too early.  This regex works as desired because I've replaced the `.*?` with `[^][]*`, which matches any characters except `]` or `[`:

```
\[\w* \w* \d{2} [\w:]* \d{4}\] \[error\] \[client [^][]*\] [^][]* Using HTTP not .*?<br />
```

I don't know what regex flavor SublimeText uses, so you may need to escape the square brackets inside the character class:

```
\[\w* \w* \d{2} [\w:]* \d{4}\] \[error\] \[client [^\]\[]*\] [^\]\[]* Using HTTP not .*?<br />
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean "reluctant", not "lazy".

There should be no intervening `<br />`, right?  Something like `((?!<br />).)*` might work.

Comment: Yes, that works, too.  This would be replacing the `.*?` in the original regex, just as I did with `[^][]*`.

Comment: It didn't quite work in my situation but both answers helped me learn a little more about regex. Thanks!